# How to write a python script that can log into this website and maintain session information?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm new to Selenium.
I want to log into this website using Python: http://www.truecaller.com

So far, this is the code I have:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.truecaller.com/sign-in/yahoo')
browser.find_element_by_name('username').send_keys('name')
browser.find_element_by_name('passwd').send_keys("pass\n")
```

It does log in but and tells me 'Signed In' but doesn't re-direct. I have tried everything. I don't understand it.

Comment: What happens when you run the code? Are you getting the security warning popup? Any errors? What if you try Chrome instead?

Comment: Yahoo logs me in, then sends me to a static page on truecaller that is plain white background with the word "Signed In" written in bold. Nothing else at all. In contrast, if you do it without the tool, it re-directs to the proper truecaller homepage.

Comment: This is what I cannot reproduce - I'm getting "SOMETHING WENT WRONG. " truecaller page..

Comment: Happened to me once or twice. Try it again, and use 'Firefox'. To me, it says 'logged in' but its a static page. In any case, I need to be able to figure out how to do this. I have tried 'mechanize' before 'selenium' but no luck. :(

Answer (score 2):

You are going in a right direction.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

# Initializing firefox browser
browser = webdriver.Firefox()

# Initializing login to Yahoo
browser.get('http://www.truecaller.com/sign-in/yahoo')

browser.find_element_by_name('username').send_keys('name')
browser.find_element_by_name('passwd').send_keys("pass\n")
browser.find_element_by_id("login-signin").click()

# Wait till browser is logged in to Yahoo, will throw error after 20 secs.
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
wait.until(lambda driver: driver.current_url == "http://www.truecaller.com/sign-in/yahoo")
```

I have written a script to scrap number details from [TrueCaller](http://www.truecaller.com). Works only with Yahoo login

- https://github.com/sumansaurabh/TrueCallerAPi/blob/cliTrueCaller/trueCaller.py fetches the number details by running the script.
- https://github.com/sumansaurabh/TrueCallerAPi Flask server to deploy the app and fetch the phone number details.

Comment: the url in this code gives 404 error now. Could u update?